# Tapping the Firebase notification is not work when app is killed(inactive)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase, notifications

I am coding my company iphone app by IOS, Swift3. The app have 3 webviews. When my App is in Forground and Background, Firebase's notification worked well. When Taping it, I can view URL page at the webview. When it is in inactive (Killed the app), I can receive the notification. but when tapping it, I can NOT view the URL page, only launching the app by default. Plz inform me the smart solution.

This is the part of my AppDelegate.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    FIRMessaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)

    //notification tapping
    let openpUrl = userInfo["openURL"] as? String
    //let openpUrl = userInfo["openURL"] as? String
    if ((openpUrl?.range(of: "blog.naver.com")) != nil) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "naverblogPushNotification"), object: userInfo)
    }else{
        if ((openpUrl?.range(of: "facebook.com")) != nil) {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "facebookPushNotification"), object: userInfo)
        }else{
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "inspotPushNotification"), object: userInfo)
        }
    }
```

}

the following is sending JASON

```
{"aps":{"alert":"Testing.. (40)","badge":1,"sound":"default"}, "openURL":"http://blog.naver.com/ins2020/22056541"}
```

I tried to search this site and follow it, but NOT worked. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: I think you should handle notification in appdelegate when app launch again after terminates `if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            if let info = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [AnyHashable:Any]{
                // handleNotification with info
            }
        }`

Comment: You mean that your code would be in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"?

Comment: yes .. right in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: I have tried your code in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions". But I am sorry tapping is NOT work. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever the user taps on the notification. it may be on
>
> UIApplicationStateActive
>
> UIApplicationStateBackground
>
> UIApplicationStateInactive

states properly handle each cases and your problem will get solved.

```
    -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{

            if(a    
pplication.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {

            //app is currently active

        }else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground){

            //app is in background

        }else if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive){

            //app is transitioning from background to foreground (user taps notification), do what you need when user taps here



           // Add your code to navigate to viewcontroller here..

        }
```

Comment: I have changed your code by Swift (UIApplicationState.inactive). I am sorry that it's not worked at INACTIVE. but Background and Active is OK. Same result. Anyway I did't get the solution...